# Django/FeinCMS ignores language/country specific url-name

Tags: python, django, feincms

we've got a Django (1.5.5) based application using FeinCMS (1.7.4).

For a page formerly only the (general) `en`-based version was configured. Later specific configurations for `en-us` and `en-ca` were added, with different `url-name`s (than used by the `en` version). This had the consequence that (`en`-based) links that had been distributed (via marketing channels) prior to that change, didn't work anymore.

Playing around with the `url-name`s I noticed, that Django/FeinCMS only honours the `url-name` which was edited last. Meaning, that ever only one `url-name` is recognised for all contexts (`en`, `en-us` and `en-ca`). The one which was edited/created last.

Does someone know a way to fix this? I've tried to find the "responsible" code, but without success.

Creating manual redirects is no option as there are too many links to specific stories/articles.

[EDIT 17-10-2016 17:53]

Based on Jonas' comments I investigated `cms_page` table in the DB a little. I noticed...

1. That there is no row in `cms_page` which represents the country specific page configurations (e.g. for `en-us` and `en-ca`).
2. Although the last-edited `url-name` and `title` are the ones of the country-specific configuration, meaning the one which "works", they don't show up in the table.

Comment: I assume this is due to feincms caching the URL in `Page._cached_url` - can you confirm this by looking at the field in the database (or through the shell)?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. We tried emptying the cache, without any luck. Only last edited `url-name` was recognised for all pages.

Comment: What is being saved in `_cached_url_`? The path _including_ the language or the path _without_ the language?

Comment: Hi @Jonas, `cms_page._chached_url` just contains the path after base url and language-country slug. Meaning no language, no country to be seen.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is relevant or not, but I noticed two things. A) that there is no row in `cms_page` which represents the country specific page configurations (e.g. for `en-us` and `en-ca`). And B) although the last-edited url-name (and title) is the one of the country-specific configuration, meaning the one which "works", in `cms_page` it doesn't show up.